# Как правильно передавать массив байт по TCP протоколу?

Tags: java, android, tcp

Требуется научить Андроид устройство передавать и получать команды в виде массива байт по **TCP** соединению. Передаваемые команды заранее известны, получаемые данные - нет. При этом, при передаче команды, первые несколько байт будут информационными. Подскажите как правильно выполнить эту задачу? Стоит ли использовать для этих целей `Serialization`/`Parcebale` или можно обойтись стандартными `inputstream`/`outputstream`. Если второй вариант, то какую команду лучше использовать для ввода/вывода. Мне кажется здесь больше всего подходит `ByteArrayInputStream`, но почти во всех примерах используется `BufferedOutputStream`, `DataOutputStream` или `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Serialization/Parcebale позволит передавать объекты. Если нужно передавать простые данные, то можно обойтись без них.

Comment: @metalurgus мне нужно отправлять команды такого вида: "0xFFF1", как я понимаю это 16-ричная кодировка? При попытке встать такое в переменную выдает ошибку. Как правильно передавать такие команды?

Comment: `int a = 0xfff1`

Comment: Если нужно динамически сохранять значения из строки, то можно так: `Integer.decode(hexString)`. Например `int a = Integer.decode("0x4d2");`

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо, а если вот так объявить - `byte a = (byte) 0xFFF1;` это будет уже другое значение?

Comment: `0xfff1` не влезет в байт. Это 2 байта. В один байт максимум влезет 2 шестнадцатиричных символа, например `0xff`

Comment: @metalurgus Спасибо, теперь многое прояснилось. Единственное, что  я не понял - это как `int a = 0xfff1` поместить в массив байт, ведь мне нужно именно его отправить. Можете посоветовать какой-нибудь туториал, я просто не знаю как загуглить это..